# Were I using undefined wrong all these years?

Tags: javascript

I happened upon something strange (at least to me), and maybe someone can elaborate on this for me:

```js
const a = undefined;
const c = {};

/** this works correctly **/
console.log(a === undefined);

/** this does not throw an exception **/
console.log(c.someProperty === undefined);

/** this throws an exception, why? **/
console.log(b === undefined);
```

Just is in the example above, why is it, that if I want to check for an objects property, with `=== undefined` which was not defined everything is okay, but as soon as I try to check for a top-level variable for being defined, I am getting an error?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0m9vrqe/).

Comment: Just mentioning the correct syntax for checking existence of top level variable is `(typeof b === 'undefined')`

Comment: I always disagreed with the wording of the error as "b is not defined", precisely because it can be easily mistaken for "b is undefined" when in fact the problem is that `b` is not *declared*.

Comment: Sure, but c.someProperty is also not declared. Is it different because it is it is a member of the c object?

Comment: @Loydms, `c.someProperty` can't be declared. It's not a valid symbol name

Comment: It's all about having a parent in the "name allocation table" of the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECMAScript Language Specification states that accessing a nonexistent variable throws a `ReferenceError` (see [GetValue](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-getvalue)) while accessing a nonexistent property results in `undefined` (see [OrdinaryGet](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ordinaryget)).

To check if a global variable is defined, you can use `typeof`, which does not throw.

```
console.log(typeof b === 'undefined');
```

Top-level variables declared with `var` also exist on the `window` object, so you can use a property access too.

```
console.log(window.b === undefined);
```

Comment: I think this is rather confusing, and imo a very bad design on the part of javascript. Basically, this means, that I have to be extra careful, which syntax I use to check for undefined variables, because the "short" syntax only works in some of the cases. What is the point of having variables that are `undefined`, and also variables that are `undeclared`? And if a variable can be either `undefined` or `undeclared`, why can't an objects property be `undeclared`, only `undefined`?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai For an object property, you can distinguish between undeclared and undefined with `'property' in obj`. JavaScript can indeed be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that b is not undefined, it is not even declared.You cannot call a variable that is not declared, be you can with one that is declared but undefined.

```
const a = undefined;
const b
const c = {};

console.log(a === undefined) //true
console.log(b === undefined) //true
console.log(c.someProperty === undefined) //true
console.log(typeof d === 'undefined') //true, it does not exist

try{
  console.log(d)
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error!')
} //error!
```